# Split string with interpolation marker

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I'm trying to figure out the best way to split a string matching a regular expression into an array

e.g

**Input:**

`[{{ content.id }}] Some {{ content.text }} with expression`

**Output:**

```
[
    '['
    '{{ content.id }}'
    '] Some '
    '{{ content.text }}'
    ' with expression'
]
```

I've tried something like

```
const r = /{{ *(.+) *}}*/g
const v = '[{{ content.id }}] Some {{ content.text }} with expression'

v.split(r)
```

but it's not working as it removes the delimiter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move the contents of your regex into parentheses. From the [manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

> If separator is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses, then each time separator is matched, the results (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array.

```js
const r = /({{[^}]+}}*)/g
const v = '[{{ content.id }}] Some {{ content.text }} with expression'

console.log(v.split(r))
```

Note that it's probably safer to use `[^}]+` than `.+` inside the `{{}}`. Also I'm not sure you really want the `*` after the last `}`? That would match `some {{ content } too`.

Comment: So simple ... love it! Thank you so much. And thanks for the note too :)